# How to show another page inside Activity?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

[image: flappy bird]

Just like the image, the first image is when the player playing, the second image is when player dead.

I believe all is within same Activity.

How to show that Game Over Text, Buttons, TextBox when player dead?

Do I have to Hide it first?

Thanks!

Comment: Given that you know when the user is dead, there you can render a fragment or in this case, just use those widgets-by default with visibility gone; and when the user is dead, set each one's visibility to visible.

Comment: Looks to me like an AlertDialog which you can customize as you like.
You can also add another activity with transparent background on top of the main one.